# Requesting echo from results page after countdown timer

Tags: java, javascript, php, ajax, request

I have a running Multiplayer Blackjack game.
Once both players have joined the countdown timer starts (60 seconds).

Once the timer runs out I want it to run another PHP page with the results on it, and then echo back the result.
However if the result is a draw, I want the countdown timer to restart at 60 seconds again.

Heres the code im currently running:

```
window.onload = function(){
countDown('my_div1', 'Result to be displayed', <?echo$newgamefinish?>); }

function countDown(elID, output, seconds){
var elem = document.getElementById(elID),
start = new Date().getTime(), end = start+seconds*1000,
timer = setInterval(function() {
var now = new Date().getTime(), timeleft = end-now, timeparts;
if( timeleft < 0) {
elem.innerHTML = output;
clearInterval(timer);
}else{
timeparts = [Math.floor(timeleft/60000),Math.floor(timeleft/1000)%60];
if( timeparts[1] < 10) timeparts[1] = "0"+timeparts[1];
elem.innerHTML = "<font color=white size=1 face=verdana>Time left: "+timeparts[0]+":"+timeparts[1];
}},0); // the lower this number, the more accurate the timer. 250 recommended 
}
```

$newgamefinish is the time left of the game, starting at 60.

Comment: That's nice... What exactly is your question?

Comment: In that code when timer reaches 0, how do I fetch another page that has results on it and then show the echo.